# python install in ubuntu docker image hangs at python-pkg-resources

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to setup a container with Python inside on a Ubuntu base. So far so basic.
However this command hangs forever for me at `Setting up python-pkgresources`. There's also a process `/usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/pycompile -p python-pkg-resources` that's grinding one CPU core:

```bash
docker run -it docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04 bash -c 'apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install  python-pkg-resources'
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:22.04' locally
22.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
2ab09b027e7f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:67211c14fa74f070d27cc59d69a7fa9aeff8e28ea118ef3babc295a0428a6d21
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:22.04
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [909 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [914 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [23.2 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [917 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1257 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [967 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [28.6 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1150 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [23.3 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [49.4 kB]
Fetched 26.5 MB in 22s (1203 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libexpat1 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0 media-types python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
  readline-common
Suggested packages:
  python-setuptools python2-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support readline-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0 media-types python-pkg-resources python2 python2-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal readline-common
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 5097 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 [347 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 [1394 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 python2-minimal amd64 2.7.18-3 [20.8 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 media-types all 7.0.0 [25.5 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2 [91.0 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 readline-common all 8.1.2-1 [53.5 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libreadline8 amd64 8.1.2-1 [153 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1 [641 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 [1977 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 [250 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libpython2-stdlib amd64 2.7.18-3 [7432 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 python2 amd64 2.7.18-3 [9098 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 python-pkg-resources all 44.1.1-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1 [128 kB]
Fetched 5097 kB in 6s (818 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-minimal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4395 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../01-python2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../02-python2-minimal_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2-minimal (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package media-types.
Preparing to unpack .../03-media-types_7.0.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking media-types (7.0.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libexpat1_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package readline-common.
Preparing to unpack .../05-readline-common_8.1.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking readline-common (8.1.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreadline8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libreadline8_8.1.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreadline8:amd64 (8.1.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libsqlite3-0_3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
Preparing to unpack .../09-python2.7_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libpython2-stdlib_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
Setting up python2-minimal (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.
(Reading database ... 5184 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2 (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pkg-resources.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pkg-resources_44.1.1-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pkg-resources (44.1.1-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up media-types (7.0.0) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up readline-common (8.1.2-1) ...
Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.1.2-1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libpython2-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up python2 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up python-pkg-resources (44.1.1-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
```

I tried different ubuntu and debian versions, different storage backends, restarting and removing `/var/lib/docker` but to no avail. The same command also hangs for some of my colleagues but works on some other machines with no obvious pattern to me. What obvious thing am I missing?

I have a hard time believing it's a general docker/ubuntu issue. The same image happily build for the longest time, so chances are high that something with my docker installation changed. Here's my `docker info` for reference:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.4
    Path:     ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  2.17.2
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 23.0.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: btrfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 31aa4358a36870b21a992d3ad2bef29e1d693bec.m
 runc version:
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.94-1-MANJARO
 Operating System: Manjaro Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.14GiB
 Name: werkzeug
 ID: PUZO:S6ZB:JI3Q:BBCI:X3UH:673F:HNHY:DOHB:CDMK:NBDN:W5J2:JUA3
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  I think the APT output suggests you're explicitly installing `python2.7`; why do you need an obsolete version of Python?

Comment: Because of some legacy tools in that image. The post above already contains a minimal reproducible example - see the docker command. I've narrowed it down to this specific package which is a dependency of pretty much anything python related.

Comment: Bitten by this too. My command is `apt-get -y install rsync unison libcap2-bin --no-install-recommends yarn`. I don't know which of those depends on python2 and causes `python-pkg-resources` to be built, but I sat there and waited and eventually it completed compiling `python-pkg-resources` and proceeded to compile `python-ttystatus`, on which it has been grinding for several more minutes at the time of this writing.

Comment: @Sahib have you ever solved this?

Comment: Turns out the `yarn` bit is the culprit in my case - no idea why installing `yarn` with `apt` pulls python2 stuff. I gave up installing it from the distro and instead installed it using npm (the base image is node), and everything is fine.

Comment: @Szczepan Hołyszewski: No, still happening. I worked around by changing the required tooling. Change of package source is of course a valid method too.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and spent a few days looking for a solution. Finally I came across this: https://github.com/MaastrichtUniversity/docker-dev/commit/97ab4fd04534f73c023371b07e188918b73ac9d0

It's an issue with python not handling a big number of open files or something like this :)

The workaround (I wouldn't call it a real solution) is quite simple - you have to LIMIT allowed maximum number of open files for a container.

So... if you start a container with simple `docker run` you must use:

`docker run --ulimit nofile=1048576:1048576 ...`

if you're using docker-compose, add:

```
ulimits:
    nofile:
      soft: "1048576"
      hard: "1048576"
```